# How can I declare a variable for each object in the JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a [data.json](https://api.myjson.com/bins/3as9e) file that contain 4 objects : a , b , c , d.

---

## Manually

I declared my variables manually.

```
var chart_a = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sa-piechart-a'));
var chart_b = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sa-piechart-b'));
var chart_c = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sa-piechart-c'));
var chart_d = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sa-piechart-d'));
```

---

## Dynamically

Now, I want to make it dynamically so it can handle all the objects in my JSON file, and it doesn't break - when I add more objects to my JSON file.

So while in the loop, I tried add :

```
chart[object] = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#sa-piechart-'+ object.toLowerCase() )); // <---- I try to add this line
```

---

I got my objects from Ajax call.

```
var data = {};
var chart = {};

for (var object in objects) {

  var total = objects[object].danger + objects[object].warning + objects[object].success ;


  data[object] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

    ['Piechart' , 'Number of Skills'],
    ['danger'   , ( objects[object].danger/total )  * 100  ],
    ['warning'  , ( objects[object].warning/total ) * 100  ],
    ['success'  , ( objects[object].success/total ) * 100  ],

    ]);

   //console.log( '#sa-piechart-' + object.toLowerCase() ); // Return #sa-piechart-a  

   chart[object] = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#sa-piechart-'+ object.toLowerCase() )); // <---- I try to add this line

}

// var chart_a = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sa-piechart-a'));
// var chart_b = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sa-piechart-b'));
// var chart_c = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sa-piechart-c'));
// var chart_d = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('sa-piechart-d'));
```

---

## Result

I keep getting `Uncaught Error: Container is not defined`

Any hints / suggestions will be much appreciated !

---

## Update

[image]

Comment: This error usually means that this element is not found in the `DOM`. Make sure that `object.toLowerCase()` really returns something, and that concatenated with `'sa-piechart-'` make up for a real/existing element.

Comment: "I got my objects from Ajax call."  Please show them

Comment: @HanletEscaño : I tried console.log, I got it to print out correctly as I expected.

Comment: Are these HTML elements being generated dynamically? If not, please post the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Container is not defined` means that DOM element is not found as mentioned in the comments. You would need to dynamically create the elements and then pass them to google pie chart. Something like this should do.

```
var el = document.getElementById('sa-piechart-' + object);
if (!el) {
  el = document.createElement('div');
  el.id = object;
  document.body.appendChild(el); // <--- I added to body. Add to required element
}
chart[object] = new google.visualization.PieChart(el); 
chart[object].draw(data[object]);
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/443/**

---

A much fancier solution (using jQuery)

```
var $el = $('#sa-piechart-' + object).length ? $('#sa-piechart-' + object) : $('<div id="#sa-piechart-' + object+'"></div>').appendTo('body');
chart[object] = new google.visualization.PieChart($el[0]);
```

Fancier demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/444/**